# Why is 'e' pronounced like 'a' in some words?

Tags: pronunciation, dialects, pronunciation-vs-spelling

I'm not a native English speaker and I have noticed that 'e' in some words are pronounced like 'a' by native speakers sometimes. For example, "Texas" sounds like "Taxes", or "Sex" sounds like "Sax" (there's even a wordplay for it), or in the famous song "Shape of My Heart", the word "Meditation" sounds like "Maditation".

Is there an explanation for this?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140271/discussion-on-question-by-sepp-a-why-is-e-pronounced-like-a-in-some-words).

Comment: Could it be the [California vowel shift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_English) which has seen /ɛ/ and /æ/ move down and back? Depends where these speakers are from, although someone in an answer mentioned the Kardashians who are from the LA area.

Answer (score 4):

I lived in Texas, and I've never heard anyone pronounce it like "Taxes."

There are regional dialects with different pronunciations of vowels (mostly in single-syllable words) that can confuse listeners.

For example, the southern US may pronounce "e" and "i" similarly which makes "six" sound like "sex," or ["pin" and "pen" may sound the same](https://lee.ces.ncsu.edu/2020/11/tell-yer-mom-nem-we-said-hi/#:%7E:text=You%20will%20also%20find%20merged,tense%20vowel%20sounds%20are%20unique.). That article calls it a merged vowel sound.

Comment: There is the Marx Brothers pun, with Groucho correcting Chico's 'Taxas' to 'Taxes, as in Dollars, Texas' and being trumped with 'Sure, Dallas, Taxas'.

Answer (score -4):

It is a speech affectation some take on. An example would be the word "best" pronounced as "bast" and have a nasal quality as well, as if the person is talking from the back of the mouth. Mostly young women are the offenders, probably influenced by social media and/or the Kardashians.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).